# Finding the length of a curve? Is this question impossible?

Tags: calculus

Find the length of the curve

$$y^2=4(x+4)^3, 0 \le x \le 2, y \gt 0$$

I applied the formula for finding the length of a curve, $$L = \sqrt{1- (f'(x))^2}$$

And in turn I got the following equation:

$$\frac{-2}{27}(-9x-35)^\frac{3}{2}|^2_0$$

But as you can tell, this is impossible to answer.

How do I do this problem?

Comment: You need to integrate that formula. Also, it's 1+f'(x).

Comment: You should learn the reasons behind formulae instead of just trying to apply them without understanding. For this particular one, http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx may help.

Comment: My engineering class doesn't really go over proofs.  It's more of a "memorize and apply" kind of approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The length integrand has **+**, not **-**. So the expression you want  with $y = f(x) = 2(x+4)^{3/2}$ is

$$L = \int_0^2 \sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2} dx = \int_0^2 \sqrt{1 + (3\sqrt{x+4})^2} dx = \int_0^2 \sqrt{9x + 37} \ dx $$